# How can copy specifics sheet to another spreadsheet using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

## Situation:

I have a spreadsheet with 10 worksheets and 15 users logging in and modifying it. I want to copy just 6 sheet from other spreadsheet.

## Script Function Needed:

The script should be copy sheet to another spreadsheet specific.

1)
Source = XXXXXX
I want to copy from Source only the sheets1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 to target.
Target = YYYYY

Note: The Target already have the sheet1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. I needs update that Target spreadsheet because I use that to make Reports. I can not use the surce because this report are confidential.

2)
The script needs to be run from the target.

## Problem:

I read a lot of forum but anyone provide a generic script about "How to Copy Sheets to anothers Sheet". All those script are very complex an I'm newbe with this.

## Test Case:

N/A

I thinks is a simple copy of sheet from one spreadsheet to another but I needs to do this in oneshot actually I am doing it manually but I have issue the system change the sheet name to Copy of XXXXX but my Reports are configured to use a specific name, that why I needs make this possible. I thinks this script will help to many people.

Thanks in Advance.

## EDIT: 14/06/2013

Hi,

Please could you help me to tunning this script to work more effective.

```
    function UpdateData() {
     var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YYYYYY');
     var sheet8 = source.getSheets()[8];
     var sheet7 = source.getSheets()[7];
     var sheet6 = source.getSheets()[6];
     var sheet5 = source.getSheets()[5];
     var sheet4 = source.getSheets()[4];
     var sheet3 = source.getSheets()[3];
     var sheet2 = source.getSheets()[2];
     var sheet1 = source.getSheets()[1];

     var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ZZZZZZ');

     sheet8.copyTo(destination).setName('Sheet8');
     sheet7.copyTo(destination).setName('Sheet7');
     Utilities.sleep(100);
     sheet6.copyTo(destination).setName('Sheet6');
     sheet5.copyTo(destination).setName('Sheet5');
     Utilities.sleep(100);
     sheet4.copyTo(destination).setName('Shee4');
     sheet3.copyTo(destination).setName('Shee3');
     Utilities.sleep(100);
     sheet2.copyTo(destination).setName('Shee2');
     sheet1.copyTo(destination).setName('Shee1');

      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
```

Comment: start a new question please, this one is already answered

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just look into the docs: [copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo%28Spreadsheet%29),  from the description:

> Copies the sheet to another spreadsheet. The destination spreadsheet
>   can be the source. The new spreadsheet will have the name "Copy of
>   [original spreadsheet name]"

The method returs the copied sheet so you can rename it:

```
sourceSheet.copyTo(targetSpreadSheet).setName('somename');
```

I hope, you know how to write a loop in JS ...